# UPDATE SQL statement not being executed SQLite3 Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to update the value of some table in a table in a database, but for some reason the SQL script isn't being executed (I think). Why is this?

```
def add_to_cart(db, itemid, quantity, name, cost):

item = {
    'id': itemid,
    'quantity': quantity,
    'name': name,
    'cost': cost
}

cur = db.cursor()
everything = []
everything.append(item)
final = json.dumps(everything)
sql = "UPDATE sessions SET data=(?) WHERE sessionid = (?)"
sessionid = get_or_create_session(db) //uuid.uuid4().hex
cur.execute(sql, (final, sessionid))
db.commit()
```

This is the sessions table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE sessions (
        sessionid text unique primary key,
        data text
);
```

Also please assume db connection working, as I know this is the case.

Comment: Post the table definition from the database

Comment: CREATE TABLE sessions (
            sessionid text unique primary key,
            data text
    );

(updated on question)

Comment: You are using a function called `get_or_create_session` If the sessionid does not exist in the database, the update will not do anything.

Comment: Thankyou @MarkBenningfield I think that will solve my problem

Comment: @CoopDaddio: Whats the point here to use `(?)` instead of `?`